# Not well formatted xml JAXB

Tags: xml, spring, spring-mvc, jaxb

m trying using the JAXB annotations to send and xml file but I saw that the nodes has this format:

```
<:subject xmlns="http://www..." xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/atom">
 <:data>maths<:data>
</:subject>
```

instead of this:

```
<subject xmlns="http://www..." xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/atom">
 <data>maths<data>
</subject>
```

I can't understand why this happens. From where insert the : symbol and why?
T

```
My model has this form:


@XmlRootElement(name="subject")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Registration {

   private String data;

    get/set
}
```

My package-info.java:

```
  @javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema (
   namespace="http://www..",
   elementFormDefault=XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED,
xmlns = { 
  @javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs( prefix=" ", namespaceURI="http://www..."),
  @javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs( prefix="atom" ,namespaceURI="http://www.w3.org/2005/atom")
})

 package mypackage.affil;

 import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm;
```

My view:

```
 <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
 <%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Create New Person</h1>

<c:url var="takeinto" value="/takedata" />
<form:form modelAttribute="takedataAttribute" method="POST" action="${takeinto}">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="data">Affiliation</form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="data"/></td>
    </tr>
```

Can anyone tells my why the symbol : appears?

Comment: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/jaxb-namespaces.html

Comment: This was working in another project i create but now not!I really can't understand.

Comment: In your package-info you have a prefix set as " ", try changing it to "" (without a space).

Answer (score 0):

You've triggered a strange bug there! My guess is that the problem is here (I've removed the Java namespace names, which you can do in a package-info.java by putting in the right `import` statements after the `package` declaration):

```java
@XmlSchema (
    namespace="http://www..",
    elementFormDefault=XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED,
    xmlns = { 
        @XmlNs( prefix=" ", namespaceURI="http://www..."),
        @XmlNs( prefix="atom" ,namespaceURI="http://www.w3.org/2005/atom")
})
```

I'm guessing that it is a combination of using a single empty string for the `prefix` and `QUALIFIED` for `elementFormDefault`. Try this instead:

```java
@XmlSchema(
    namespace="http://www..",
    elementFormDefault=XmlNsForm.UNQUALIFIED,
    xmlns = { 
        @XmlNs(prefix="atom", namespaceURI="http://www.w3.org/2005/atom")
})
```

That is, `UNQUALIFIED` and only providing `xmlns` for the parts that you want qualified. It's possible that you'll need to specify the namespace on `@XmlElement` tags throughout (the documentation is somewhat unclear) so I also recommend refactoring that out into a constant in an interface; that makes things clearer too.

Comment: Also, if you're dealing with lots of classes that need qualification, put them in a different namespace and use a separate `@XmlSchema` declaration there that says that they _are_ qualified by default. But usually it's where you need elements from a particular “standard” namespace that things get complex. (FWIW, I generate my schemas fully qualified normally — being explicit is good — but I can understand the reasons why not.)